# Insert a comment in a python string

Tags: python

I want to insert my String `"#kalkakak"` in another string called `fil`. The problem is that this element `'#'` (that i need) transform all my String in a comment and the program don't do nothing. Please help

Comment: As long as the hash symbol is inside quotes it shouldn't be turning anything into a comment. How are you trying to insert it?

Comment: Could you share some more details, like the code fragment which is not working?

Comment: "dsadsa#ddsddsda" i did something like this

Comment: Like I said, if the hash symbol is inside quotes it won't turn anything into a comment. Can you please post your code?

Comment: This works perfectly inside the quotes, should not convert it into comments...  could you provide some more info...
variable_name = "dsadsa#ddsddsda" will store your value.

Comment: line[0:line.find("#")] i have to create a substring from the string line, until the character # appears

Comment: I'm not having any problems running that. Please post all relevant code and the full text of any errors you are receiving.

Answer (score 1):

```
fil = "dsadsa"
fil = fil + "#kalkakak"
print fil
```

The result is correctly "dsadsa#kalkakak". Nothing is considered a comment.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the # thing in proper quotes ("") then it won't comment out anything.
And if you want to comment out #kalkakak then write it outside quotes and like this "#kalkakak#"